# Django : delete multiple sessions without 'for loop'

Tags: django, session

Usually, I've deleted **multiple sessions** through '**for loop**'.

I'd like to **change** it into '**delete query with  filter' to speed up** like following sample codes.

However, I don't know how to solve this problem.

---

[ **Case 1** ] - *works well*

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session 
from datetime import datetime

def clear_expired_sessions():
    for s in Session.objects.all():
        if s.expire_date < datetime.now():
            s.delete()
```

[ **Case 1 with update query** ] - *not working*

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session 
from datetime import datetime

def clear_expired_sessions():
    Session.objects.filter(expire_date<datetime.now()).delete()
```

Which yields `NameError: name 'expire_date' is not defined`

---

[ **Case 2** ] - *works well*

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session 
from accounts.models import UserProfile

def delete_specific_session():
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(username="Tim")

    for s in Session.objects.all():
        if s.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id') == user.id:
            s.delete()
```

[ **Case 2 with update query** ] - *not working*

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session 
from accounts.models import UserProfile

def delete_specific_session():
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(username="Tim")

    Session.objects.filter(????=user.id).delete()
```

In this case, what should be substitute for `???=user.id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason attempt 1 fails is basic Django query syntax: you must use `__lt` for comparisons:

```
Session.objects.filter(expire_date__lt=datetime.now()).delete()
```

Attempt 2 can never work, as the session model has no relationship with the user one.